# Three.js: Cast shadows on a transparent material

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to convert the lighting on a MeshPhongMaterial:

[image: MeshPhongMaterial]

So that the visible portion is transparent to the dom element beneath it. I just want to keep the shadows. If I use a ShadowMaterial, I lose the radial lighting effect and just get the shadows from the objects:

[image: ShadowMaterial]

I tried applying a transparent png texture as the map to the MeshPhongMaterial but it shows as fully transparent with no shadows.

Here is the effect I am trying to recreate (produced using html5 canvas drawing):
[image: HTML5 Canvas]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looking into if there is any way to blend the white as an alpha channel or something (I have no idea what I'm doing :)

Comment: No luck with blending. I tried every variation here https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/CustomBlendingEquations

Comment: I came up with a solution that worked for my particular use case, but I posed a new question that is a bit more generic and is specifically what I was trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000003/three-js-cast-lightshadow-to-shadowmaterial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that will technically work. I created another webgl canvas and three.js scene. In the new scene I created a single plane that uses a CanvasTexture of the first canvas as its material's alphaMap. I then had to write a shader that inverted the colors on the first canvas. This was applied using THREE.EffectComposer. Still needs some tweaking but this was the result:

[image]